# Does React ignore props that are array buffers for updating elements, if the key is the same?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am wondering how React decides to re-render certain elements. I have an app where then the user switches tabs, I update an `<AssetContainer>`. Sometimes that container will contain an `asset` with the same `document_id` which is used for the key. I am noticing that when I create an asset, my effect runs to set a thumbnail URL to a blob fine. I switch tabs, create an asset with the same file and it makes another new blob. Then when I switch back to the first tab, it will NOT re-render. Despite being passed in a new `asset.thumbnail.image`, it treats it as the same. I should note `asset.thumbnail.image` is an array buffer. Does this make React disregard the value when looking for updates?

I have code like this:

```js
<AssetContainer>
{assets.map((asset) => (
      <Asset
        key={asset.document_id}
        thumbnail={asset.thumbnail!.image!}
        thumbnailFormat={asset.thumbnail!.format!}
        hasClaim={!!asset.provenance}
        errors={asset.errors}
        size="80px"
      />
    )
)}
</AssetContainer>
```

Within `<Asset>` I have the following effect and code with `<AssetView thumbnailUrl={thumbnailUrl} size={size}></AssetView>` where that is defined as:

```js
// The effect in Asset
useEffect(() => {
  let blobUrl;
  if (thumbnail) {
    const imgData = Array.isArray(thumbnail)
      ? thumbnail
      : new Uint8Array(Object.values(thumbnail));
    const blob = new Blob([imgData], { type: thumbnailFormat });
    blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    // this is what stops firing every time i switch tabs which should re-render the elements based on new data in the tab
    console.log('setting thumbnail url', blobUrl);
    setThumbnailUrl(blobUrl);
  }
  return () => {
    if (blobUrl) {
      URL.revokeObjectURL(blobUrl);
    }
  };
}, []);

// The AssetView definition for the tag invocation above
const AssetView = styled.div`
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  width: ${(props) => props.size};
  height: ${(props) => props.size};
  margin-right: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background-color: #434646;
  background-image: ${(props) =>
    props.thumbnailUrl ? `url("${props.thumbnailUrl}")` : 'none'};
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center;
`;
```

The short version is this: Every time I switch tabs, `<Asset>` renders as expected. I see a `console.log` fire every time before the return of `<AssetView>`. However the `useEffect` of `<Asset>` is not firing when an array buffer prop is updating when the `key` is the same as before. Unsure why.

**Update why doing [thumbnail] in the effect is not the answer**
This is not the issue as things update fine due to higher level components remounting. If I do this suggestion, every time i switch tabs it will re-run the use effect and generate a new blob URL which is not what I want. The behavior as-is is that in Tab A it will generate Blob-1 and in Tab B it will generate Blob-2. When I go back to Tab A I want Blob-1 but still get Blob-2.

I believe the issue is that the `key` is the same for both tabs (which I will fix), but am unsure how high one needs to go (if possible) for React to disregard the `key`. If it was only the `key` that was causing the caching, it shouldn't even generate Blob-2.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't `thumbnail` be included in your effect dependencies array?

```
useEffect(() => {
    // ...
}, [props.thumbnail]);
```

Otherwise, the effect would only run once [with an empty array](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#conditionally-firing-an-effect)

Comment: Will update with comments above as to why this is not the solve